# Make Google App Engine as Load Balancing Server

Tags: google-app-engine, load-balancing

I'm wondering if anyone knows any script in Python or Java to setup Google App Engine as Load Balancer server?

I choose GAE, because of 100% uptime and free, so it would be the best to setup as Load balancer.

So what I want to do is set up a GAE app (a load balancer application) in "www.domain.com" - using Google Apps, it will share the load to all my servers (with round-robin, or any technique), but when all servers are down, show maintenance page which is host in GAE.

Is this possible?

Comment: How do you plan to split the load, will you just redirect to the final servers, or you will use GAE as a middle man between all requests? If you're just developing a new application you might as well do it directly on GAE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it, but you'd

1. incur extra latency by requiring an extra hop from google app engine to your servers
2. <strike>have all your servers public to the web, since otherwise google app engine won't be able to redirect to them</strike> Edit: apparently this is incorrect.  See Nick Johnson's comment below!
3. have to implement something in google app engine to keep track of what servers you have up and how and when to route to them

Seems like it might not be worth it, but it'd be cool if you did it and posted some numbers about how it works!

Comment: Point 2 is inaccurate - you can use Secure Data Connector to fetch resources from behind a firewall.

Comment: Oh, interesting, I didn't know that.  I'll edit my answer and give you credit, thanks.

Comment: So i guess this idea is possible. i would like to make this for our forums that i would like to expand it to more than 1 server to share the load. and i think it's worth to develop. Thanks for your answer. i gave you a credit.

Comment: If you think my answer is the correct one, can you mark it as such?  At Stack Overflow, if you've asked a question and believe somebody has answered it well, it's good form to mark that answer as correct (and not just upvote it).  Thanks and good luck with your project.

Comment: Two things: 1 secure data connector is deprecated.  2 your gae wont be free unless it wont use up the free quotas in particular front instance hours.